# Xcode : UITextfield uneditable

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, sdk, uitextfield

Is ther a way to make a UItextfield uneditable ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[theTextField setEnabled: NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.